# Async/await call to asmx service

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, async-await, asmx

I am consuming a asmx service and trying to do async/await while trying to call it

Currently My controller is like below

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
   var data = _repository.GetDataFromAsmxService(somedata);
}
```

//RepositoryClass Method

```
public List<ObjectToReturn> GetDataFromAsmxService(somedata)
{
   var res = _asmxService.GetReportData(somedata);
   var result = process(res);
   return result;
}
```

Upon further looking at refrence.cs file generated found there were void async and onCompleted methods for equivalent calls.

So i changed it to

```
        private void GetReportDataCallBack(object sender, GetReportDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var res = e.Result;
            var result = process(res);
        }

        public List<ObjectToReturn> GetDataFromAsmxService(somedata)
{
   _asmxService.GetReportDataCompleted +=GetReportDataCallBack;
   _asmxService.GetReportDataAsync(somedata);

}
```

but now the callback happens to the Event delegate so my controller expecting a return data won’t get it. 
**what is a better way to call async/await from controller and get the data from asmx webservice**

Code From Refenrece.cs
//Generated code

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("ApiAuthenticationValue")]
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://webservice.com/GetReportData", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://webservice.com/")]
        public GetReportDataResponse GetReportData([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://webservice.com/")] GetReportDataRequest GetReportDataRequest) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("GetReportData", new object[] {
                        GetReportDataRequest});
            return ((GetReportDataResponse)(results[0]));
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public void GetReportDataAsync(GetReportDataRequest GetReportDataRequest) {
            this.GetReportDataAsync(GetReportDataRequest, null);
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public void GetReportDataAsync(GetReportDataRequest GetReportDataRequest, object userState) {
            if ((this.GetReportDataOperationCompleted == null)) {
                this.GetReportDataOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnGetReportDataOperationCompleted);
            }
            this.InvokeAsync("GetReportData", new object[] {
                        GetReportDataRequest}, this.GetReportDataOperationCompleted, userState);
        }

        private void OnGetReportDataOperationCompleted(object arg) {
            if ((this.GetReportDataCompleted != null)) {
                System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
                this.GetReportDataCompleted(this, new GetReportDataCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Let's see the full method signatures of your repository. It really relies on what that is before you can consume it a different way.

Comment: @Cameron public List<ObjectToReturn> GetDataFromAsmxService(somedata)

Comment: Can you provide the code for `GetReportData`?

Comment: that is a service webmethod, i have code from refrence.cs

Comment: @ScottChamberlain added the reference.cs file ref of that method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is a [Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw(v=vs.110).aspx) and what you want to do is [wrap that up in a task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can await it. You do this via a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public async Task<List<ObjectToReturn>> GetDataFromAsmxServiceAsync(GetReportDataRequest somedata)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<GetReportDataResponse>();
    _asmxService.GetReportDataCompleted += GetReportDataCallBack;
    _asmxService.GetReportDataAsync(somedata, tcs); //we pass tcs in so it can be used from the callback.
    GetReportDataResponse res;
    try
    {
        res = await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        //unsubscribe from the handler when done so we don't get a leak.
        _asmxService.GetReportDataCompleted -= GetReportDataCallBack;
    }

    var result = process(res);
    return result;
}

private void GetReportDataCallBack(object sender, GetReportDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var tcs = (TaskCompletionSource<GetReportDataResponse>)e.UserState;
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    }
}
```

You will also need to change your controller to be async too

```
public Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var data = await _repository.GetDataFromAsmxServiceAsync(somedata);
}
```

[Here is a good article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) explaining how to convert from synchronous MVC code to async MVC code and explains why even though `Index` is now called `IndexAsync` it will still work as your controller for Index.

Comment: does exception propagate to controller in this pattern if one is thrown inside repository

Comment: Yes it does exceptions should handle like the non async version. They will get raised on the line with the await.

Comment: The thing that propagates the exception is the `tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);`, that causes any exceptions that where asynchronously raised from inside the event to be raised when you `await` the returned task in `GetDataFromAsmxServiceAsync` and in `IndexAsync`

Comment: I'm looking into exactly this problem, myself.  I've seen a solution that uses Task<> -> GetAwaiter().GetResult() that seems much simpler, and removes the OnCompleted handler.  How does this compare to the use of TaskCompletionSource?  Is it an acceptable (and much simpler) solution, or is it missing something?  (I'm learning async-await and new to consuming ASMX services in this way.)
`Task<GetReportDataResponse> res = _asmxService.GetReportDataAsync(somedata);
var result = process(res.GetAwaiter().GetResult());`

Comment: @JMD Calling `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will cause the exact same deadlock issue just calling `.Result` will. The only thing `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will do for you is it will unwrap the `AggragateException`, you still have all of the problems you would get if you had synchronously called `.Result` instead.

Comment: @JMD Also, `Task<GetReportDataResponse> res = _asmxService.GetReportDataAsync(somedata);` does not compile, `GetReportDataAsync` returns `void` not `Task<GetReportDataResponse>`. If it did return `Task<GetReportDataResponse>` the entire code could be simplified to `result = process(await _asmxService.GetReportDataAsync(somedata));` The entire point of the `TaskCompletionSource` is to convert somthing that uses events to show when you are done to somthing that uses Tasks to show when you are done. Read the first link in my answer about EAP for more info.

Comment: Yep, I'm partway through that article but it makes no mention of GetAwaiter() or its comparison to EAP.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I see now, the second article ties together EAP and Tasks (async/await).  Still trying to wrap my head around it.  EAP is simple enough, and I've been using it for ages.  Wrapping EAP in a Task makes my head hurt.

Comment: @JMD the actual term for the task version is "[Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx)", there is also a 3rd kind "[Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx)". APM is the `BeginXxxxx(`/`EndXxxxxx(IAsyncResult result)` pairs you see on functions. To go from APM->TAP you use [`TaskFactory.FromAsync(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx), for EAP->TAP you use `TaskCompletionSource` like shown in my answer.

Comment: Is it safe to wrap the SOAP client in a `using` block with this technique, and if not how should the client object be disposed?